# getting trouble to manage file data after importing the excel file in laravel 5.8

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, vue.js, laravel-excel

I want to send many emails at a time by importing `excel` file. Now, I am importing the `excel` file and keeping the data into a `variable` as an array.
I am using `maatwebsite/excel version 3.1`. After importing, the file data storing to the variable as nested array and excel file's rest of the column keeping the null values also.I tried to use `array_filter` but it's not working fine. This is the screenshot what I am getting as response now - [response in console](https://i.paste.pics/6KAGK.png)
.

In EmailsController -

```
public function sendEmailUsingFileAndSave(Request $request)
{
    //here is $content, $fromemail, $fromname etc..

    $file = $request->file('file');

    $import = new EmailsImport;
    Excel::import($import, $file);
    return $emails = $import->data;
    foreach($emails as $email)
    {
        Mail::send('email.content', ['content' => $content], function($message)
             use ($email, $subject, $fromemail, $fromname) {
                  $message->to($email)->subject($subject);
                  $message->from($fromemail, $fromname);
             });
     }
}
```

And in `app\imports` folder `EmailsImport.php` is -

```
<?php

namespace App\Imports;

use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToCollection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\Importable;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithValidation;

class EmailsImport implements ToCollection, WithValidation 
{
    use Importable;

    public $data;

    public function collection(Collection $rows)
    {
        $this->data = $rows;
    }
 }
```

I am expecting the response like - `(2) ["abc@example.com","xyz@example.com", "abc@another.com"]`

My import sample excel file is - [sample excel file](https://i.paste.pics/6KAN0.png)

I am trying to do this for long time would someone help me please to solve this problem?

Comment: take a look at [this](https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel/issues/1867) thread. maybe your goal is to make a validation

Answer (score 0):

So your problem is the filtering part?

Then add the following code:

```
Excel::import($import, $file);

$emails = [];
foreach ($import->data as $item) {
  $item = array_filter($item, function($value) { return !is_null($value) && $value !== ''; });
  foreach ($item as $i) {
    $emails[] = $i;
  }
}

foreach($emails as $email)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `Maatwebsite\Excel` is seeing some of the empty cells in your excel file as part of the row, so when you use the `ToCollection` interface and setting `$this->data` to be equal to $rows you are assigning a two dimensions array into `$this->data`

There are many ways to solve this but I would suggest to use a foreach loop on the `$rows` collection and add only the first cell of each row to `$this-data`, try something like that:

```
class EmailsImport implements ToCollection, WithValidation 
{
    use Importable;

    public $data = [];

    public function collection(Collection $rows)
    {
        foreach ($rows as $row) {
            $this->data[] = $row[0];
        }
    }
 }
```